# How to set jquery ui icon as background image per css?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

How can I set a jquery ui icon as a background image per a css container?

Something like:

```
.MyClass {
  background: url("ui-icon-plus");
}

// Existing div...want to add icon to left-align
<div class="MyClass">
   //Other stuff in there that expands and collapses
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

How can I get the following text to appear to the right of the icon?

```
<div class="MyClass">Whatever</div> <!-- no workee--> 
<div class="MyClass"><span class="MC">Whatever</span></div> <!-- works --> 

 .MyClass {
      width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url("../../Content/themes/base/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png")/*{iconsContent}*/;
      background-position : -16px -128px; 
}
.MC {
   padding-left: 20px;   
}
```

Comment: your image url have to be relative to where the css-file is stored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to apply the corresponding CSS class:

```
<div class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></div>
```

Assuming that you have the correct jQuery UI `.css` file with those classes defined.  If you look at the jQuery `.css` file you'll see that it is using `background-position` to find the icon in the [CSS sprite](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

Look at the styles of the icons on [Themeroller for examples](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. My constraint is not being able to modify existing html scaffolding so I need to modify via css.  The gist of it is to add + icon to an existing div (can't resize the div) and then set the icon to a - after the section below it expands.

Comment: @JaJ: Glad you found this helpful. Sorry I'm just now getting around to responding to your comment, but my first suggestion would be do just resize the `div` to `16px` by `16px` using CSS (and copy the CSS from `ui-icon-plus`), but you say here that you can't resize it. I see in your update that you did take this route and that seemed to solve your issue, that's good. As for your update, that seems out of the scope of this question and you may have better luck asking a new one. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I would use:

```
<div class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></div>
```

But if you need the css in your own class for some reason:

```
.MyClass { width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(images/ui-icons_333333_256x240.png); background-position: -16px -128px; }
```

Comment: Thx for the reply! However, the issue and constraint that I have is that I need to add the image via css to an existing div so I can't re-size the div itself. Is that still possible using sprites?

Answer (score 2):

To get the icon you can directly refer the sprite like for plus.

```
 .MyClass {
width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png)/*{iconsContent}*/;
background-position: -16px -128px; 

}
```

Comment: Thx for the reply!  However, the issue and constraint that I have is that I need to add the image via css to an existing div so I can't re-size the div itself.  Is that still possible using sprites?

Comment: I dont think you have to resize the div, sprites will act as normal background image.you can add a screenshot of what you are getting after you apply this class.

Comment: Hi, I just updated my original post. CAn you take a look when you get a second?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -3):

You need to call the absolute position of the image for example:

```
.MyClass { background: url("http://yourdomain.com/somefolder/ui-icon-plus.ext"); }
```

Comment: jQuery UI icons are not stored in individual image files, they are applied using a [CSS sprite](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)